# Finding $\min f(x)$ where $f(x)=\int_0^1 |t-x|t\,dt \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, optimization

Can I write the integral as $f(x)=\int_0^{x} |t-x|t\,dt + \int_{x}^1  |t-x|t\,dt$ 
so that $f(x)=\frac{2x^3-x}{2}+\frac{1-2x^3}{3}$

But here I'm restricting $x$ to the interval $(0,1)$ and I need $x$ to be any real number.

So what should be the correct approach here to find the minimum value of $f$?

Comment: differentiate f(x), and set it equal to 0.

Comment: @DougM I don't think you can differentiate under the integral sign here -- I think the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ of $|t-x|t$ has to be continuous for $0 \le t \le 1$ and all $x$, but it doesn't even exist when $t = x$.

Comment: The original poster has already found that $f(x) = \frac 13 x^3 - \frac 12 x + \frac 13$. differentiate that.

Comment: @DougM Okay, sure. I thought you meant to do the differentiation before splitting into cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x \le 0$ then $|t-x| = t-x$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ so that $$\int_0^1 |t-x|t \, dt = \int_0^1 (t-x)t \, dt = \frac 13 - \frac x2$$ which has its minimum value of $\dfrac 13$ at $x=0$.

Likewise, if $x \ge 1$ then $|t-x| = x-t$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ and the minimum can be worked out accordingly.

Comment: Is this the complete solution or in addition to what I did (assuming correctly)?

Comment: There are three cases: $x \le 0$, $0 < x < 1$, and $x \ge 1$. You can determine the minimum in each case and select the least of these by inspection. I did the first case, you did the second.